# Using the IMDB-Grabber images dont display

Tags: php, html

Using this addon:
https://github.com/FabianBeiner/PHP-IMDB-Grabber

My pictures cannot be load:

I do it like this:

```
$IMDB = new IMDB("'".$name."'");
$poster = $IMDB->getPoster('big', true);
$html_string = 
"<td><img class='img-responsive' 
alt='$name' src='$poster' width='96px' height='142px'>
 </td>";
```

The html code is for the example of Pulp Fiction is:

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="Pulp Fiction" src="http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTkxMTA5OTAzMl5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNjA5MDc3NjE@.jpg" width="96px" height="142px">
```

And the output looks like this:
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/12819454/12179193/c099cb2c-b575-11e5-8a73-3a85fbf54665.PNG
[image]

Can you help me?

The console says

```
GET http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTQ0MzYwMDY5OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTYwNDc3Mjk5._V1._SX96_SY140_.jpg 403 (Forbidden)
```

Comment: I can't replicate this. The image URLs in the img tag and the error message are different.

Answer (score 0):

IMDB apparently does not like you hot-linking their images from your webpage (as recognised through the Referrer).

As specified in the IMDB TOS and on the page you linked to, they do not allow scraping their site either.

You can however:

- [licence their data](http://www.imdb.com/licensing/?ref_=cou_2)
- use their [free data](http://www.imdb.com/interfaces) pursuant to their [conditions](http://www.imdb.com/help/show_leaf?usedatasoftware), particularly personal, free, non-commercial use. Not sure about images in that case, though (haven't looked at the contents of their datasets in a while).